# How to define an inheritable tree class in C# to build tree like data structure made from different class types?

Tags: c#

I‘Ve been reading around this topic for some time, but I simply don't know the C# syntax well enough. Hopefully this is clear to you and you are willing to help me out. The examples I found are tree structures of the same type or class, which are not what I need here.

In short, I want to be able to define an arbitrary class, like NodeClassA, NodeClassB, NodeClassC below and be able to attach any number of these to each other to form a tree data structure as illustrated arbitrarily below.

Each Node should be able to access its parent.

Can anyone help properly define the MyTreeClass below?

NodeClassB 
__NodeClassC 
__NodeClassA 
____NodeClassB 
____NodeClassB 
____NodeClassA 
__NodeClassA 
____NodeClassC 
__NodeClassB 
__NodeClassC

```
class MyTreeClass
{
    public void AddChild(T NodeClassX) { }
    public T GetChild() { }
}
class NodeClassA:MyTreeClass
{
    public void foo(int a) { }
}

class NodeClassB : MyTreeClass
{
    public void foo(int b) { }
}

class NodeClassC : MyTreeClass
{
    public void foo(int c) { }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have done?

Comment: Why different classes? Do they have anything different from each other?

Comment: Your generic class is missing the definition of `T`: `class MyTreeClass<T>`

Comment: Is this question for homework?

Comment: You should probably modify your example if you are really looking for a tree structure that holds different types. The way you have it presented, all three types are identical.

Comment: @Alex The issue with what I have done is that the  MyTreeClass syntax does not compile, and generic type T does not exit because its not been declared.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the classes are different because they perform very different functions, but it will be helpful to arrange them in a tree data structure.

Comment: @CJohnson No it isn't homework, I'm 35, i code in my spare time not professionally.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) which is a common way to model tree structures, e.g. a file system where you have a leaves (files) and containers (folders) and containers can contain other containers or leaves themselves.

In your case, at least the way you described it so far, it is a bit simpler because there is no behavioral difference between those nodes. So for your structure, the nodes can actually be shallow and you only need to implement the composition within your base class. In that way, you don’t have leaves but only (different) containers.

```
public abstract class BaseNode
{
    public IList<BaseNode> Children
    { get; } = new List<BaseNode>();
}

public class NodeClassA : BaseNode { }
public class NodeClassB : BaseNode { }
public class NodeClassC : BaseNode { }
```

And then you can already build your structure.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in a strict type safe way because type safety is ensured at compile time, which requires the types to be statically declared. But the tree is built dynamically at runtime with different node types.

The way to go is to have a static node data type which can be generic. Different types of data can be derived form a given base data type. Use polymorphy to work with them. I.e. use the same set of methods with different implementations.

```
public class TreeNode<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }

    private List<TreeNode<T>> _children = new List<TreeNode<T>>();
    public IEnumerable<TreeNode<T>> Children => _children;

    public TreeNode<T> AddChild(T data)
    {
        var node = new TreeNode<T> { Data = data };
        _children.Add(node);
        return node;
    }

    public void VisitPreOrder(Action<T, int> action, int level)
    {
        action(Data, level);
        foreach (TreeNode<T> node in Children) {
            node.VisitPreOrder(action, level + 1);
        }
    }
}

public class Tree<T>
{
    public TreeNode<T> Root { get; } = new TreeNode<T>();

    public void VisitPreOrder(Action<T, int> action)
    {
        Root.VisitPreOrder(action, 0);
    }
}
```

Now you can have data classes that are totally unrelated to the tree:

```
public class A
{
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public virtual void PrintLine()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"A {Index}");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void PrintLine()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"B {Index}");
    }
}

public class C : B
{
    public override void PrintLine()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"C {Index}");
    }
}
```

Create a tree structure from your example

```
TreeNode<A> node;

var tree = new Tree<A>();
tree.Root.Data = new B { Index = 0 };            // NodeClassB
tree.Root.AddChild(new C { Index = 1 });         // __NodeClassC
node = tree.Root.AddChild(new A { Index = 2 });  // __NodeClassA
node.AddChild(new B { Index = 3 });              // ____NodeClassB
node.AddChild(new B { Index = 4 });              // ____NodeClassB
node.AddChild(new A { Index = 5 });              // ____NodeClassA
node = tree.Root.AddChild(new A { Index = 6 });  // __NodeClassA
node.AddChild(new C { Index = 7 });              // ____NodeClassC
tree.Root.AddChild(new B { Index = 8 });         // __NodeClassB
tree.Root.AddChild(new C { Index = 9 });         // __NodeClassC
```

Because each data type (base type or derived type) does its own thing appropriate for its type, you don't need to know its exact type. This is called polymorphy. This prints the tree structure:

```
tree.VisitPreOrder((item, level) => {
    Console.Write(new string('_', 4 * level));
    item.PrintLine();
});
```

> B 0
>   ____C 1
>   ____A 2
>   ________B 3
>   ________B 4
>   ________A 5
>   ____A 6
>   ________C 7
>   ____B 8
>   ____C 9

Note that you don't need to know the concrete data type of `T` when declaring the `Tree<T>` and `TreeNode<T>` classes since `T` is generic. You could as well declare

```
var stringTree = new Tree<string>();
var intTree = new Tree<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your arbitrary class inherit or compose a collection of some kind. For example your arbitrary classes could all be lists. The augmentation would be that the add method sets the child's parent and that the parent is a property.